# iOS AVPlayer too slow when streaming online video

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play online video content. Server supports byte ranges as according to RFC 2616.
Thing is that it takes too long for AVPlayer to have playable status.
For a 1GB video (duration = 1h 45min) it takes 1min-2min to start playback. I notice that seek works rather good after that.
Playing same video on default Android media player takes 15sec to start.

It seems as if AVPlayer downloads chunks in different parts of media space for better seek support. But I want video to start as soon as possible. Is such a thing possible - to configure AVPlayer for quicker play?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: In the end, no. The way AVPlayer works wasn't critical for the feature I was working on.